# creating java help using single HTML file

Tags: java

I have one HTML file which contains 200 definitions and i don't want to create 200 HTML files. I want to create java help using that file such that if user click on TOC(table of content) list and user can reached at the particular definition without scrolling that html documentation.

Comment: please add more info. The question is not answerable in its present form.

Answer (score 0):

First study how to make tree like structure using [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and then study how to show html page in Jframe using  [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).